# Where and how to define const integer in a file in c++?

Tags: c++, integer, constants

I have a class Example and I have a return value for my function(), which is EXIT_CODE, but I'm not sure how and where to define the constant integer as return value, should be in the hpp or cpp file, and more specifically as a global variable or not?
This is my hpp file.

```
Class Example
{
  private:
    //code
  public:
    int function();
};
```

This is my cpp file.

```
int Example::function()
{
  //do something
  return EXIT_CODE;
};
```

Comment: Keep the scope as small as possible. If the only user is the cpp file, define it in the cpp file. If users of the `Example` class need to know what the value means, you define it in `Example`'s header and possibly as a `public` and `static` member of `Example`.

Comment: Side note: if the return values all have significance, they are all codes representing something, consider using an `enum`.

Comment: @user4581301 so if I have many exit codes, I need to use enum? I know that is good practice to use enum class and not a enum, is that correct? And if I have an enum class how can I use it with my int function(), because the value is not an integer.

Comment: There is no "need". This is all about writing safer and easier to read code. If you just return codes the program will use for signaling, an `enum` is usually easier to read and harder to accidentally misuse. For example, you can't easily return something that isn't a valid code because the compiler will catch the mistake for you. If the compiler guarantees something can't happen, you might not need as strenuous error checking later. If you need to return numbers, say there are three error codes and all values greater than zero represent an actual number, `enum` may not be the right choice.

Comment: @user4581301 Did you mean less than zero? Because I can't declare an enum variable with a negative value. When I have an enum class, I need to cast the return value, because its not an integer?

Comment: Apologies for being unclear. What I was trying to describe is a case where you should prefer an integer over a enum. Imagine a function like `recv` that returns `int`. -1 is error, 0 is socket disconnected, and anything greater than 0 is the number of bytes read. `enum` doesn't make sense in this case because not all of the returned values are diagnostic codes. If the number is >0, you may well be performing math on it.

Comment: So I have to use integer when I have a negative value, and when do I have a > 0 its possible to use enum?

Comment: You can make an enum with negative values. ([see points 7 and 8 here](http://eel.is/c++draft/enum#dcl.enum))The thing is you don't want to use an `enum` when an `int` is a better fit, and if the return value is going to be more than just special codes that can be covered by an `enum` use an `int`. The objective is to write descriptive code, and if you're using a value as a number, it should be a number. But if you're using a value as a code, it can have a better, more descriptive name to go with it.